# Setting path parameters in AWS API Gateway JavaScript SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set path parameters when making calls to API Gateway endpoints via the JavaScript SDK and not having any luck.  It looks like I either have something misconfigured or there is a bug in the SDK generation.

I am able to successfully call endpoints that do not take path parameters but when I try to pass in a parameter to be used as a path parameter the SDK just replaces the path parameter with a blank and my call fails.

Example, assume `client` is a properly initialized API Gateway client.  I have an endpoint called `/measurement` with a child of `/measurement/{id}`.  I am able to call both directly.

`client.measurementGet({},{});` - successfully calls my `/measurement` endpoint
`client.measurementIdGet({"id": "1234"}, {});` - Browser makes a call to `/measurement/` instead of `/measurement/1234`

Looking at the source of my apigClient.js, it appears that the SDK generator is not putting path parameters into the list of parameters that it's looking for.  For example, the code of my generated `measurementIdGet` method looks like this:

```
    apigClient.measurementIdGet = function (params, body, additionalParams) {
        if(additionalParams === undefined) { additionalParams = {}; }

        apiGateway.core.utils.assertParametersDefined(params, [], ['body']);

        var measurementIdGetRequest = {
            verb: 'get'.toUpperCase(),
            path: pathComponent + uritemplate('/measurement/{id}').expand(apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, [])),
            headers: apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, []),
            queryParams: apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, []),
            body: body
        };

        return apiGatewayClient.makeRequest(measurementIdGetRequest, authType, additionalParams, config.apiKey);
    };
```

I dug into the `assertParametersDefined` and `parseParametersToObject` and it looks like those methods are expecting a list of parameters to look for.  In both cases the SDK has generated empty lists instead of putting my path parameter in there.

If I manually update the generated file to change the two lines to

`apiGateway.core.utils.assertParametersDefined(params, ['id'], ['body']);`

and

`apiGateway.core.utils.parseParametersToObject(params, ['id'])`

The SDK makes the proper call.

Am I missing something in my configuration or is there a bug in the code generator?

Comment: I have this same issue here. any update on this? @mason

Comment: Same issue for me. I asked about it on the forum and haven't gotten any answer: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=734395. Anyone know if the SDK generator is open source? Couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Sorry to bug but any update here ? Still getting this issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cloud formation like me. You will need to add it in the [RequestParameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters).

for a resource like this /api/pets/{id}/attributes/{attrid}  following code works

```
  PetsByIdAttributesByAttridGetMethod:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Method'
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
      ResourceId: !Ref PetsByIdAttributesByAttridResource
      HttpMethod: GET
      AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.id : true
        method.request.path.attrid : true
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyLambda.Arn}/invocations
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but for those new to AWS that may still run into this issue like I did, I hope this answer helps:

In the AWS API Gateway Console, make sure that you specify the "URL Query String Parameters" in the "Method Request" for your "GET". Then re-deploy your API and generate the SDK again. This time the apigClient.js will be generated with the defined Query Parameter keys correctly filled in to the calls to `assertParametersDefined` and `parseParametersToObject`.

[image: API Gateway Console where you define Query Parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're importing a swagger definition to create the API, defining your `parameters` at the method level as opposed to the path level will result in a generated SDK with the `key` filled out and should work correctly.

```
{
    ...
    "/path/{to}/resource": {
        "get": {
            "parameters": [ // define here
                "name": "to",
                "in": "path",
                ...
            ],
            ...
        },
        "parameters": [] // not here
}
```

Although defining `parameters` at the path level is correct according the the Swagger spec and API Gateway does use them in the created API, it appears that API Gateway disregards them in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

This look's like an issue doesn't parse the params.

https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/498[enter link description here](https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/498)